# How to determine if a record is the first/last one in an iteration?

Tags: ruby

Its a thing that made me thinking several times. In this example I have an array and this array has 10 values that should be seperated by commatas but after the last one there shouldnt be a commata so I used a counter:

```
data = ["john", "james", "henry", "david", "daniel", "jennifer", "ruth", "penny", "robin", "julia"]
counter = 0 
count = data.size
sentence = String.new
data.each do |name|
     if counter == (count-1)
          sentence += name
     else
          sentence += "#{name}, "
     end
     counter += 1
end
```

But this is so dirty isnt there any method to find out if the current object (in this case "name") is the frist or the last one in the iteration?

Comment: `data.join(', ')` if I understood you correctly

Answer (score 28, accepted):

in this specific case, `data.join(', ')` would do, more generally `data.each {|d| #do stuff
unless d.equal? data.last}`

Comment: `==` would fail if there is another 'Julia' in the list. `d.equal?(data.last)` tests for object equality.

Comment: of course - always forget the not unique case - thanks - i've corrected the answer so no-one copies without reading the comments

Comment: Disclaimer: `obj.equal?` method compares with `object id` prefer using `==`

Answer (score 10):

You should just write `data.join(', ')`. Anyway, answering your question:

> Isn't there any method to find out if the current object is the first or the last one in the iteration?

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]

xs.each.with_index do |x, index|
  if index == 0
    puts("First element: #{x}")
  elsif index == xs.size - 1
    puts("Last element: #{x}")
  else
    puts("Somewhere in the middle: #{x}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `name==data.last` if your array is of unique elements

Otherwise use directly

```
data.join(', ')
```