# Scroll to a specific tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I know this issue is kind of typical problem for web development.
But i'm stuck in this problem for almost 3 hours.
If you can help me or give me hints, i appreciate it.

**What i want to do**
After user clicked a link, scroll automatically to specific tag on next window.

Sequence
1. User is on TaskWindow
2. User pushes a link to HistoryWindow on TaskWindow
3. Application shows HistoryWindow and scroll to specific tag automatically.

**Environment**
ruby 2.1.1p76 / Rails 4.2.0 / CoffeeScript / Javascript

**What i tried**
I tried two ways.

1: Use assets/javascripts/histories.coffee

*assets/javascripts/histories.coffee*

```
ready = ->
    scrollToElement($('.history-group-<%= @group_histories.count-1 %>'));

scrollToElement = (ele) ->
    $(window).scrollTop(ele.offset().top).scrollLeft(ele.offset().left)
```

Problem

- Error at `<%= @group_histories.count-1 %>` (But if i write literal variable, it works.)
- Other controllers load this coffee file.

2: Use histories/index.html.erb

*histories/index.html.erb*

```
....  
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    function scrollToElement(ele) {
        $(window).scrollTop(ele.offset().top).scrollLeft(ele.offset().left);
    }

    scrollToElement($('.history-group-<%= @group_histories.count-1 %>'));
<% end %>
```

Problem

- Not work. Nothing happen.

**Question**
How method is better to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

What your are looking for is anchor links:

```
<a href="/foo#bar">Foo</a>
```

This will automatically scroll to the element with the id attribute `bar` when the browser has loaded `/foo`.

If there is no matching element the browser will scroll to the top (which is the default anyways).

To create an anchor with the Rails routing helpers:

```
link_to("Index", foos_path(anchor: 'bar'))
```

Comment: Thank you for advising. It works correctly with literal value like `<li><%= link_to 'History', histories_path(anchor: 'history-group-18') %></li>`. If i want to change it dynamic path, i assume i need to write like `<li><%= link_to 'History', histories_path(anchor: "history-group-#{@group_histories.count-1}") %></li>` but TaskWindow doesn't have group_histories variant for now because of unnecessary request. Should i request this variant to DB only for this problem?

Comment: I really don't understand your question. One important factor that I think you are missing is that the URL hash is transparent to the server by design. That means that you cannot see on the server if the request URL contains a hash.

Comment: Another issue with you script above is that your script uses `<%= @group_histories.count-1 %>` however the assets in Rails are compiled at deploy time - not per request as it would be super slow. So the count will quickly get out of date.

Comment: Sorry for lacking explanations. My `controllers/histories_controller.rb` - `def index` execute `@group_histories = History.all`. And `views/histories/index.html.erb` will generate tags dynamically by the count. Pseudo codes are `<% (0..@group_histories.count-1).each do |i| %><div id="history-group-<%= i %>">...</div><% end %>`. Meanwhile `views/tasks/index.html.erb` has a link to the histories_controller-index and it should go to bottom of tags generated by the above @group_histories loop.

Comment: Just add an `history-group-last` id to the last element and link to that instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859072/how-to-determine-if-a-record-is-the-first-last-one-in-an-iteration

Comment: Thank you for suggestion of a workaround. I knew it can work in this case. I thought there is another typical way like using javascript, but is the solution you suggested common one in rails developers?

Comment: I don't know if you could say that - anchor links have been around since forever and its pretty much the accepted way to link to a specific element. You cant really use javascript to do the same thing unless you are using ajax to replace the page contents since your basically starting from zero when the page reloads.